# Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 - Configuration Progress

Tags: microsoft-office

Every once in a while (like about every 2 months), I open a Word Document, and it opens, but then the following screen opens.  While it's running, it keeps me from scrolling all the way through the document; which can be quite frustrating if your in a meeting.  It runs for about 5 or 10 minutes, then it says it wants to reboot.

I have had Office 2013 installed for over a year, so I don't know what it thinks it's configuring.  This isn't the way Windows Updates come, is it?

[image]

Part 2 - what would be the task to kill in Task Manager?

Comment: Sounds like you need to run the Office installation repair tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852

Comment: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)

Comment: I started that last night, forgot to see if it finished or what it reported.  Since this only happens every couple of months, it will be hard to know what fixed it.